# max value of data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have multiple division with different data attribute value, with same class
also need to get the value data-value using jquery. Example i have data-value groups 2, 3, 5 
to get the desired result is 5 among the group

```
<div data-value="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-value="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-value="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
etc.
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no direct way but this will do

```
var dataList = $(".maindiv").map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
}).get();
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, dataList));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pgbf3o9f/

Comment: When `dataList` is an empty array, the `Math.max.apply()` will return `-Infinity`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `$.each()` method, like below:

```
var result = 0;

$('.maindiv').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).data('value') > result) {
        result = $(this).data('value');
    }
});
// result now contains the max value, so do what you want with it
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code.

```
function MaxId(selector) {
    var max=null;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        var id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
        if (isNaN(id)) { return; }
        if ((max===null) || (id > max)) { max = id; }
    });
    return [max];
}
alert(MaxId('div.maindiv'));
```

or you can also try as below.

```
Math.max(one, two, three);
```